# GLEW Linker Error

Tags: opengl, linker-errors, glew

I am following along with tutorials on the site, http://openglbook.com/, and I have run into a problem I cannot solve. In the second tutorial, they begin using shaders. After entering in their code, I get linking errors such as,
"[Linker error] undefined reference to '_ imp____glewGenVertexArrarys'"
as well as a lot of others. My development environment is Dev-C++. I have linked against glew32.lib, but it still fails to recognize some of the GLEW functions. I have been able to utilize some functions from the GLEW library, but when it comes to these shaders, something is going wrong and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Dev-C++ is defunct. Move on to Code::Blocks or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't realize they were defunct. And I love Code::Blocks so much more than Dev-C++ lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem with glew and VS 2010.
I can't remember the link that said it but I think they talked about statically linking glew by defining the makro GLEW_STATIC.

Btw for me the solution was to recompile GLEW from source on my own.

**EDIT**
I think I found the link: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/462433-glew-and-mingw/

Comment: Alright I'll try that and see if I can get it to work. I can't compile it in Windows, right? I need Linux or at least UNIX?

Comment: If you need it on windows you can do it on windows. Get the latest build from the website http://glew.sourceforge.net/ and follow the instructions. For me it worked simple because they had a VS Project for building everything needed. But you should at first try to define GLEW_STATIC and see if the errors vanish( and don't forget to link glew32s.lib when you want to link static)

Comment: When you say define GLEW_STATIC, you just mean put in "#define GLEW_STATIC" at the top of the file, right?

Comment: Well I would define it by a compiler option. I do not know where to put this in your IDE but if it uses gcc compiler from minGW I can say that the commandline of gcc(g++) has to contain "-DGLEW_STATIC" which will define this makro for the whole compilation process.